# Trying to build a custom CRM application using VB + MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crm

So I'm a first time poster, long time user of this site. Anytime I have a question, I always make sure to come here first. Anyway, I'm trying to build a CRM application using an existing MySQL Database and Visual Studio 2010 in VB. Here's the code I have so far, and I'm trying to return the results of the mysql query into a list view, then make it so when someone double clicks on a row, it'll open that account. Here's the code I have so far.

I've been working on this for several hours, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me out. I am an extreme noob at VB, but decent with MYSQL.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class mainWindow
Public sConnection As New MySqlConnection
Private Sub mainWindow_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = system; PASSWORD =; DATABASE = system"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub searchBtn_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles searchBtn.Click, Button1.Click
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "Select * from tblclients"
    Dim sqlAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim Table As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection

    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(Table)
    End With
    For i = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
        With dataView
            .Items.Add(Table.Rows(i)("id"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("fname"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("lname"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("company"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("email"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("phone"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("state"))
                .Add(Table.Rows(i)("zipcode"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

If anyone can help again, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is the error you get? Apart from that, use the `Using` statement for the connection, the DataAdapter and the  Command. Don't open the connection on Form_Load but only when you use it and close it as soon as possible(`Using` will do that for your).

Comment: Aside from not actually pulling the information requested, it gives me this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the new on MySqlDataAdapter

```
Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
```

This will fix your problem with the `Object reference not set.....`, but, really you should follow the suggestion from Tim Schmelter. Never keep a global connection around for the lifetime of your form/application. It will be a disaster waiting to happen (especially with MySql that seems more sensitive to leaked connections)

```
Private Sub searchBtn_Click_1(.....) Handles searchBtn.Click, Button1.Click

    Using sConnection = new MySqlConnection(.......)
    Using sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from tblclients", sConnection)
        sConnection.Open()
        Using sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
            Dim Table As New DataTable
            Dim i As Integer
            With sqlAdapter
                .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
                .Fill(Table)
            End With
        ...... ' the rest of your code that fills the view'
        End Using
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

In this way you close and dispose the connection, the command and the adapter immediately after they are no more requires ALSO in case of exceptions. [See Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Comment: "Missing the new on MySqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter"

This actually fixed that issue, the other one I'm having is making a row clickable, so that when someone clicks on it (or double clicks) it opens the record on a new form. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @BradJTrammell if this answer the question you could choose to upvote and accept it. Trust me, it is not useful to insert another question here because you will never receive the same attention if you post a new question. Try it it is free.... :-)